# Не передаются данные из response в state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Данные приходят с сервера, но не попадают в state (использовал breakpoint) и поэтому, как я понял, ломается map(). Хотелось бы узнать, что я делают не так.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();

  }

  getData = () => {
    fetch('url') //url with json data
        .then( response => response.json()) // 
        .then((data) => { // console.log(data) -> Array (32) {id: 13, firstName: 'Ivan', ...}
          this.setState({
            users: data.user,
          });
        })


  }

  render(){

      return(
        <div>
          {this.state.users.map((firstName) =>{ // Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

            return(
              <h1>{firstName}</h1>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что `componentDidMount()` вызывается лишь раз после рендера и по этому в state не успевают попадать ваши данные. Вам нужно использовать `componentWillMount()` данный метод вызывается до рендера.
Пример того как сейчас у вас работает: Мы вызывает `render` -> далее мапим `this.state.users` -> он ничего не находит и вызывает ошибку -> вызываем `getData()` -> записываем данные в `state`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: [],
    }
  }



  componentWillMount(){
    this.getData();

  }

  getData = () => {
    fetch('url') //url with json data
        .then((response) => {
          response.json().then((data) => {
             this.setState({
               users: data
             });
          });
    })
  }

  render(){

      return(
        <div>
          {this.state.users.map((user, id) =>{

            return(
              <h1 key={id}>{user.firstName}</h1>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: К сожалению, ошибка Cannot read property 'map' of undefined в render() осталась

Comment: @A.Sivov, после `render()` законсольте `this.state.users`  что он ответит?

Comment: Пустой массив [] и undefined

Comment: @A.Sivov, а в`.then((data) => {..}` проконсольте `data.user`

Comment: показывает undefined

Comment: @A.Sivov, Вы не правильно поняли, `.then((data) => {console.log(data.user)});`. Мне кажется что в вашем `data` не существует ключа с именем `user` и по этому он записывает в `state` `undefined`. Я видоизменил ваш код, попробуйте так.

Comment: Понял, изменил ключ на существующий `firstName`, но, тем не менее `undefined` все еще присутствует.

Comment: @A.Sivov, внес правки в ответ.